# What does 'const' do when used in a pointer to pointer rvalue const function argument?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

```
void func(int **&&const x) 
{   
    *(*x) = 32; 

}

void main()
{
    int *pi = new int{ 64 };

    printf("x : %d\n", *pi);

    func(&pi);

    printf("x : %d\n", *pi);
}


Outputs: 
x : 64 
x : 32
```

When using a pointer to a pointer to an rvalue const, the value is still modifiable within the function. Is there any purpose for using a **&&const as a function argument. The code was compiled using VC2013 with C++ Compiler Nov 2013.

EDIT: I do receive the warning "anachronism used : qualifiers on reference are ignored" but it's probably better to fail to compile completely. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It allows to change the value, but not to change the 1st level pointer.

Comment: A decent compiler reports: 'const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘int**&&’'

Comment: `x` is certainly not a "pointer to a pointer to an rvalue const".  If it were legal, it would be something like a "const rvalue reference to pointer to pointer" - but a const reference is nonsense.

Comment: If you found one of these answer useful you should consider [accepting one of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3):

gcc 4.8.2 doesn't consider it valid code:

```
// snippet of your code
void func(int **&& const x)
{
    *(*x) = 32;

}
```

... and the compile ...

```
$ g++ -fsyntax-only -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 foo.cpp
foo.cpp:2:26: error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘int**&&’
 void func(int **&& const x)
                          ^
```

I'm going to assume that VC 2013 is wrong to allow that code to compile.

Comment: VC2012 will complain about it if you crank the warning level up: "anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored."

Answer (score 1):

References are alias, and alias does never change. So, `&const` and `&&const` have no sense at all. They are semantically equivalent in all matters to `&` and `&&`.

So is the case that that constructions aren't allowed (perhaps for simplifying metaprogramming). Not only for `int**&&const`, but also for `int& const` or `int&& const`.

In consequence, qualifying a reference with `const` have no purpose at all. Your funcion can be rewritted then to:

```
void func(int **&& x) 
{   
    *(*x) = 32; 
}
```

The next token is a rvalue-reference. Its purpose is detecting if the receiving argument is anonymous or not. For example:

```
int **ppi = &pi;

func(ppi);
```

doesn't work, `ppi` is not an anonymous variable (it's a name), but `&pi` it is (it's only an address, so, a `pure rvalue`).

It's important to remark that, inside `func`, `x` is a lvalue-reference, and not a `rvalue-reference`, since inside the function block, `x` is no more an anonymous variable (its name is just `x`), irrespective of the "anonymousity" of its origin.

Answer (score 0):

Use of pointers and `const` can be confusing. Here is an explantion.

```
int i;
int * ip1 = &i;
```

`ip1` can be changed to point another object. `*ip1` can be changed to have another value.

```
int const* ip2 = &i;
```

`ip2` can be changed to point another object. `*ip2` can not be changed to have another value.

```
int * const ip3 = &i;
```

`ip3` can not be changed to point another object. `*ip3` can be changed to have another value.

```
int const* const ip4 = &i;
```

`ip4` can not be changed to point another object. `*ip4` can not be changed to have another value.

Now, coming to your question,

```
void func(int **&&const x)
```

is not valid code in `C++`. It is not valid in `C++11` either.

Assuming you meant,

```
void func(int **&const x)
```

`x` is `const` reference to a pointer to a pointer to an int. That means, you can't change what `x` points to but you can change `*x`. You can also change `*(*x)`.

Comment: This doesn't cover the OP's case.  The OP was asking about a `const` rvalue reference to a non-`const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer to a non-`const` `int`.